# Rich snippet rating and review data not showing on Google SRP

Tags: rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool

Searching Google for for [responsible+pest+control+reviews](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/?url=https://responsiblepestcontrol.net/happy-clients/) returns no reviews data for my website even through I have correct review markup.

Is it an error in page tagging or just a matter of time before Google discovers the mark and then displays the review ratings?

Comment: Sorry but this type of question has been asked many times already on Pro Webmasters in various forms.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not guarantee that Rich Snippets will show up for search results from a particular site even if structured data is marked up and can be extracted successfully according to the testing tool.

---

[Quote from Google](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-rich-snippets#howlong):

> **How long does it take for rich snippets to be visible?**
>
> Once you've marked up your site's content, Google will discover it the next time we crawl your site (although it may take some time for
>   rich snippets to appear in search results, if we do choose to display
>   rich snippets for your site)